# How to update/manage data for react-table - useRowState plugin behaviour is unclear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I am using react-table (https://react-table.tanstack.com/) to build a table-like component. Amongst various types of columns few of them are intractable. That means based on the interaction the data(provided to the Table) must be updated.
As an example,
In the attached screenshot you will notice a column with a type checkbox. Now based on the click to the checkbox, data is also supposed to be updated.

[image]

As a solution, I am using the `useState` hook and passing the data.
and Updating them onClick event to the checkbox.
[image]

[image].

This seems a working solution to me, but I found a plugin documented in react-table documentation that implements basic state management for prepared rows and their cells.https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useRowState
As it does not have any working sample associated, I am unable to figure out how this plugin can be used to resolve my current requirement.

Here is the codepen link for the working sample
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-hill-vz7to?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3):

react-table provides an example called *Editable Data*. Essentially you provide a custom cell renderer to the columns array and pass an update function to the `useTable` hook. Inside the custom cell renderer you have access to this function and call it whenever the data changes.

This is the example edited so that it fits your use case: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-flower-dkq5x

The relevant changes are:

1. The custom cell renderer:

```
// Create an editable cell renderer
const CheckBoxCell = ({
  value,
  row: { index },
  column: { id },
  updateMyData, // This is a custom function that we supplied to our table instance
}) => {
  const onChange = e => {
    updateMyData(index, id, !value)
  }

  return <input type='checkbox' checked={value} onChange={onChange} />
}
```

2. We don't override the default cell renderer in the `useTable` hook.
3. We pass our custom cell renderer to the columns array:

```
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Name',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'First Name',
            accessor: 'firstName',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Last Name',
            accessor: 'lastName',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        Header: 'Info',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'Age',
            accessor: 'age',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Visits',
            accessor: 'visits',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Status (available)',
            accessor: 'status',
            Cell: CheckBoxCell,
          },
          {
            Header: 'Profile Progress',
            accessor: 'progress',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    []
  )
```

4. We adjust the data so the status works with check boxes (just for this example)

```
const newPerson = () => {
  const statusChance = Math.random()
  return {
    firstName: namor.generate({ words: 1, numbers: 0 }),
    lastName: namor.generate({ words: 1, numbers: 0 }),
    age: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30),
    visits: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    progress: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    status:
      statusChance > 0.5 ? true : false,
  }
}
```

Comment: hello, I have the same issue with this author but something went wrong when I tried to toggle my checkbox, it just happened once. I mean the state update got delayed.